# Flip vertically both layer and layer mask

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to create an image similar to this:

[image: original image]

So I have taken an image of my pregnant girlfriend, lying flat on the ground, imported the image into Photoshop CC, and created a layer mask to cut her out from the background.

Now I want to flip the cutout vertically to create the reflection. So I duplicated the layer and did Transform > Flip vertically. However, this only flips the image layer, not the layer mask.

So, how do I flip both the image and the layer mask and how do I make them stay together if I move them to their correct position?

*Edit:*

This is my situation:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The layer mask DOES flip with the layer for me, and it's default behaviour. I suspect what you have done is to unlink the layer mask from the layer.

Simply click between the layer and the layer mask, to toggle the little link icon.

[image]

You also say you want them to "stay together" when moved, and linking them (more accurately *keeping them linked*) will accomplish this too.

Comment: Somehow, this default behaviour doesn't for me. See the edit to my question for an image of my situation.

Comment: I am not sure why there is a marquee selection (the dotted lines) in your image. Perhaps you are selecting the contents of the layer and flipping that, rather than flipping the entire layer? Deselect everything, highlight the layer and edit > transform > flip vertical

Comment: Yes! Deselecting everything finally solved my issue!

Comment: That's great, the image should look superb when its finished